# WhatsAPI (WhatsAPP) - Exception Error

Tags: php, whatsapp

I'm looking at this code: https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI

On the page: **/src/php/EXAMPLES.php**

I've made the following changes (which I think is all I need to amend. I have obviously used different IMEI number and Mobile numbers for this example):

```
        $userPhone        = '447799999999';      # Telephone number including the country code without '+' or '00'.
        $userIdentity     = '98B898B898B8';      # This is tipically the IMEI number.
                                                 # If you are using an iOS device you should input your WLAN MAC address.
        $userName         = 'John Doe';          # This is the username displayed by WhatsApp clients.

        $destinationPhone = '447788888888';      # Destination telephone number including the country code without '+' or '00'.
                                                 # For groups: [phone number]-[group id].
        $debug = TRUE;
        $w->requestCode('sms', 'GB', 'en');
        $w->registerCode('123456');
```

but when navigating to this example.php page on my server I receive the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'There was a
>   problem trying to request the code.' in
>   /whatsapp/src/php/whatsprot.class.php:1174
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /whatsapp/src/php/EXAMPLES.php(49):
>   WhatsProt->requestCode('sms', 'GB', 'en') #1 {main} thrown in
>   /whatsapp/src/php/whatsprot.class.php on
>   line 1174

I just want to know where I'm going wrong, can anyone shed some light? Thanks

Comment: hello where is code ?? https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI

Answer (score 1):

Where did you instantiate the WhatsProt class?
You need to use this line:

```
$w = new WhatsProt($userPhone, $userIdentity, $userName, $debug);
```

Comment: do you have other code? bcoz last 6 hour i searching whatsapp php code only :(

Comment: email me bibaswann.mail@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

also ensure that you have the latest src file it keep changing without notice just re-download the src file and overwrite the current one